# ARCGIS IOS Development Delegates Not Connecting/Working

Tags: ios, delegates, maps, arcgis

I'm new to ARCGIS so be easy on me.

I have an `UIView` in my nib which I changed into an `AGSMapView` which I then referenced in my `UIViewController` class which also holds the `<ArcGIS/ArcGIS.h>` package. Okay I think I've done everything right so far.

After running the code below in the `viewDidLoad`, I can add the view to get the map to appear on the simulator.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:kTiledMapServiceURL];
AGSTiledMapServiceLayer *tiledLayer = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:url];
[self.mapView addMapLayer:tiledLayer withName:@"kTiledMapServiceURL"];
```

From here I want to access the `- (void)mapViewDidLoad:(AGSMapView *) mapView` so I can add the users location.

Anyways I add the `AGSMapViewLayerDelegate` and set `self.mapView.layerDelegate = self;`. 
Now my code looks like something below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer"];
AGSTiledMapServiceLayer *tiledLayer = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:url];
[self.mapView addMapLayer:tiledLayer withName:@"Basemap Tiled Layer"];

self.mapView.layerDelegate = self;
} 

- (void)mapViewDidLoad:(AGSMapView *) mapView 
{
 [mapView.locationDisplay startDataSource];
}
```

Anyways for whatever reason I can never get `mapViewDidLoad` to be called, or for that matter any other events in ARCGIS. I believe I'm doing everything I should, If anyone has any ideas why this is occurring, I would greatly appreciate them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is possible that you don't adopt the protocol  to your View Controller like:

```
ViewController: UIViewController <AGSMapViewLayerDelegate>
```